# GPIO vs GPIO-HD vs GPIO-FAST

Tags: microcontroller, gpio, microprocessor, nxp

I am using NXP [S32K148](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/S32K-DS.pdf) in one of my design. In the IO signal table I can see that for some pins, pad type is written as:

- GPIO
- GPIO-HD
- GPIO-FAST

May I know the difference between these three?

Comment: They are defined in the datasheet. Different current capabilites, fall and rise times etc. What did you want to know about them? I agree the datasheet isn't very nice in the way it gives the infromation, but all the informaiton is there. If it matters to you depends on what you're using the pins for.

Comment: I want to know can I use any of these GPIO's for enabling and disabling another IC

Comment: As long as you're within the DC electrical specifications (table 17, 19) and AC electrical specifications (table 21, 23), you can use any of these for general I/O purposes.

Comment: It depends on what the other chip is and how do you use the GPIO to enable/disable that another chip. Without details, no one can answer if you can use the GPIO pins to do what you want.

Comment: @Justme,I need to drive this ic,https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps4h000-q1.pdf?ts=1692885875191&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F please see page no 26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differnces between these GPIO pins is documented in the datasheet.

Looking at tables 17 and 18, you can see what the signals are capable of for slower signals. Looking at tables 21 and 23 you can see what the signals are capable of in terms of switching speeds and strengths etc.

In general, all of this GPIO pins can be used for "normal" things, such as turning an FET on and off at 1Hz. If you are trying to something where speed or signal strength matters, then you'll need to read the datasheet in detail.

In summary: they all operate at standard GPIO pins, if you need to worry about the differences you're doing something outside the norm.

Answer (score 1):

Your chip has logic level inputs. Your MCU has logic level outputs. They are compatible. Any type of output from MCU will do.